# Invalid object name 'inserted' inside trigger

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, triggers

I'm using EF Core and for payment table I define the following trigger that is valid, but when I am using my app, while inserting the new payment the context returns error on save:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update:
> Error: An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'ApplicationDbContext'.
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'MRPayments.inserted'

This is the trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Payment_Log
ON MRPayments.Payments
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Action nvarchar(10)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [MRPayments].[inserted])
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [MRPayments].[deleted])
            SET @Action = 'UPDATE'
        ELSE
            SET @Action = 'INSERT'
    END
    ELSE
        SET @Action = 'DELETE'

    INSERT INTO MRLogs.Payment_Logs (PaymentId, Action, OldValues, NewValues, LogDate)
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN @Action = 'DELETE' THEN [MRPayments].[deleted].Id 
            ELSE [MRPayments].[inserted].Id 
        END,
        @Action,
        CASE 
            WHEN @Action = 'UPDATE' THEN dbo.GetOldValues_Payment([MRPayments].[deleted].Id) 
            ELSE NULL 
        END,
        CASE 
            WHEN @Action = 'INSERT' THEN dbo.GetNewValues_Payment([MRPayments].[inserted].Id) 
            ELSE dbo.GetNewValues_Payment([MRPayments].[deleted].Id) 
        END,
        GETDATE()
    FROM [MRPayments].[inserted]
    FULL OUTER JOIN [MRPayments].[deleted] ON [MRPayments].[inserted].Id = [MRPayments].[deleted].Id
END
GO
```

I'm using fully qualifier with schema table names but the same error occurs when I use just `inserted` instead of `[MRPayments].[inserted]`. I have read that I need to clarify in `applicationdbcontext`, but after that the same error occurs:

```
  modelBuilder
        .Entity<Payment>()
        .ToTable(t => t.HasTrigger("trg_Payment_Log"));
```

this is the full code with function and with inserted and deleted instead of [MRPayments].[inserted] and [MRPayments].[deleted] as someone mentioned at the comment section. But it's still not working corectly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Payment_Log
ON MRPayments.Payments
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Action nvarchar(10)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  inserted)
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
            SET @Action = 'UPDATE'
        ELSE
            SET @Action = 'INSERT'
    END
    ELSE
        SET @Action = 'DELETE'

    INSERT INTO MRLogs.Payment_Logs (PaymentId, Action, OldValues, NewValues, LogDate)
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN @Action = 'DELETE' THEN deleted.Id 
            ELSE inserted.Id 
        END,
        @Action,
        CASE 
            WHEN @Action = 'UPDATE' THEN dbo.GetOldValues_Payment(deleted.Id) 
            ELSE NULL 
        END,
        CASE 
            WHEN @Action = 'INSERT' THEN dbo.GetNewValues_Payment(inserted.Id) 
            ELSE dbo.GetNewValues_Payment(deleted.Id) 
        END,
        GETDATE()
    FROM inserted
    FULL OUTER JOIN deleted ON inserted.Id = deleted.Id
END

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetOldValues_Payment(@PaymentId uniqueidentifier)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OldValues nvarchar(max)

    SELECT @OldValues = 
        'PaymentStatus: ' + COALESCE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), deleted.PaymentStatus), 'NULL') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
        'ApplicationUserId: ' + COALESCE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), deleted.ApplicationUserId), 'NULL') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
        'PaymentValuePLN: ' + COALESCE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), deleted.PaymentValuePLN), 'NULL') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    FROM deleted
    WHERE deleted.Id = @PaymentId

    RETURN @OldValues
END

GO

CREATE FUNCTION GetNewValues_Payment (@PaymentId uniqueidentifier)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewValues nvarchar(max)

    SELECT @NewValues = CONCAT(
        'PaymentStatus: ', COALESCE(NEW.PaymentStatus, 'NULL'), CHAR(13), CHAR(10),
        'ApplicationUserId: ', COALESCE(NEW.ApplicationUserId, 'NULL'), CHAR(13), CHAR(10),
        'PaymentValuePLN: ', COALESCE(CAST(NEW.PaymentValuePLN AS nvarchar(max)), 'NULL')
    )
    FROM inserted AS NEW
    WHERE NEW.Id = @PaymentId

    RETURN @NewValues
END

Go
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The trigger code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh MS SQL server

Comment: It's not `[MRPayments].[inserted]`; that would reference an object called  `inserted` on the **schema** `MRPayments`. It's just `inserted` and `deleted`.

Comment: Your functions (such as `GetNewValues_Payment`) *can't* access the pseudo-tables `inserted` and `deleted; the `FROM inserted AS NEW` will reference the object `inserted` on the `USER`'s default schema. I am, in truth, surprised that function could be created.

Comment: @ThomA should I have an error while creating the function? I'm using sql-server 2022 and I can create such a function. But as you mentioned (and it is the answer for this question) there is a problem with inserted within function scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `deleted` and `inserted` inside other functions. They are only accessible from the trigger scope.

You can also improve your code by using `CONCAT_WS` and table aliases.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Payment_Log
ON MRPayments.Payments
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO MRLogs.Payment_Logs
    (PaymentId, Action, OldValues, NewValues, LogDate)
SELECT
  ISNULL(i.Id, d.Id),

  IIF(i.Id IS NULL, 'DELETE', IIF(d.Id IS NULL, 'INSERT', 'UPDATE')),

  CASE WHEN i.Id IS NOT NULL AND d.Id IS NOT NULL THEN
    CONCAT_WS(NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10),
      'PaymentStatus: ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), d.PaymentStatus), 'NULL'),
      'ApplicationUserId: ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), d.ApplicationUserId), 'NULL'),
    'PaymentValuePLN: ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), d.PaymentValuePLN), 'NULL')
    )
  END,

  CONCAT_WS(NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)
    'PaymentStatus: ' + ISNULL(i.PaymentStatus, 'NULL'),
    'ApplicationUserId: ' + ISNULL(i.ApplicationUserId, 'NULL'),
    'PaymentValuePLN: ' + ISNULL(CAST(i.PaymentValuePLN AS nvarchar(max)), 'NULL')
    )
  END,

  GETDATE()

FROM inserted i
FULL JOIN deleted d ON i.Id = d.Id;

GO
```